# How can I debug the request to detect why my HttpPost never fires?

Tags: postman, asp.net-core-webapi, csrf, .net-5

Having the following HttpPost action

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/Test")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("Something")]
    [HttpPost]
    //[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Something()
    {
        return Ok(new
        {
            Result = true
        });
    }
}
```

If I enable the `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` tag, it works fine.

Then It seems that my post (from Postman) should sent the CSRF token, in that case:

*I configure the __RequestVerificationToken (as a Header or as a Body with x-www-form-urlencoded)*
[image: Setting the __RequestVerificationToken]

*Making sure that the token get updated*
[image: Read the Token]

But I still get a 400

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-4b7d669686a083fbba09be86b6841e42-847918b0b6ca656b-00"
}
```

I tried to debug the request in order to discover what is happening?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        var initialBody = context.Request.Body;

        using (var bodyReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(context.Request.Body))
        {
            string body = await bodyReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(body);
            context.Request.Body = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body));
            await next.Invoke();
            context.Request.Body = initialBody;
        }

        //await next.Invoke();
    });
}
```

But I haven't found anything special.
How can I find out what is generating this 400 Bad Request?

Comment: Hi @Erick Asto Oblitas ,any update?If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? If not, could you please follow up to let me know?

Answer (score 0):

You may misunderstand what is the process of testing endpoints protected with an XSRF token in Postman.

`Pre-request script` to set the value of the xsrf-token environment variable. And from the script, you need be sure the `{url}` you called is a view which contains input with `name="__RequestVerificationToken"`.

Then you send post request to the `api/test`.

Here is my working code:

1.Index.cshtml:

```
<form method="post">
    //if it does not generate the token by default
    //you can manually add:
    //@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 
</form>
```

2.Set the environment:

| VARIABLE | INITIALVALUE |
| --- | --- |
| member-url | https://localhost:portNumber |
| xsrf-token |  |

[image]
3.Be sure apply the enviroment:

[image]

4.Pre-request script:

[image]

5.API:

```
[Route("Something")]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Something()
{
    return Ok(new
    {
        Result = true
    });
}
```

After you get 200 response, you can see the token value in your created environment.